# change SymbolIcon based on Text value

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, conditional-statements

**The Need**
I'm setting this in a Data Template.. What I want to do is display a different icon per Hardware type with one special exception. The 3 different Icons I will be using are; Shop, OutlineStar, and OtherUser.  All Registers will have the Shop Icon, All Servers will have the OutlineStar, and all display boards will have the OtherUser icon.

**The Exception**
In some cases a register can also be a server, so I would want to switch the Icon to Outline Star in that case.

**The Code**

```
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedInTemp"
                          x:DataType="DeviceMenu">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Padding="5">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FacilityName}" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Shop" Margin="0,5,12,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Hardware}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind HostName}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Converter to get the desired symbol and place the logic of getting the symbol based on Hardware in the converter.

Converter

```
public class SymbolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // value is Hardware
        // Logic to return symbol
        //retun Symbol.OutlineStar
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML to use this converter

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedInTemp"
                      x:DataType="DeviceMenu">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Padding="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FacilityName}" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind Hardware, Converter={StaticResource SymbolConverter}}" Margin="0,5,12,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Hardware}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind HostName}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

You will have to add this converter to the page/app level resource.
I am not sure what you will need to decide the Symbol, however, if you need something else also then you can pass that in ConverterParameter.